# Persistent dark mode while navigating pages with a dark/light mode toggling option

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to implement persistent dark mode on web pages, as when a user navigates through pages, their choice will be remembered. Also, I added a toggle dark/light mode button, for better user experience. Thus I came up with this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#002f30">
<style>

body {
  padding: 25px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.btn {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #10101c;
    color: #10101c;
    border-radius:0.5rem;
}

a { 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #006262;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #192841;
    font-style: italic;
}

body.dark {
  background-color: #10101c;
  color: #778899;
}

body.dark .btn {
    background: #10101c;
    color: #708090;
    border: 1px solid #002e43;
    border-radius:0.5rem;
}
body.dark a { 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #778899;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #d5c4a1;
    font-style: italic;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<h1 style="margin-top: 0">page 1</h1>
<h2 style="margin-top: 0">Toggle Dark/Light Mode</h2>
<p>Click the button to toggle between dark and light mode for this page.</p>
<p>This is a link to a second page <a href="test2.html">click</a></p>
<button id="mode" class="btn" onclick="toggle()">Toggle dark mode</button>

<script>
function toggle() {
// This bit is for the toggling between dark and light mode
    let element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("dark");

    // This part is for toggling the text inside the button 
    var toggle = document.getElementById("mode");
      if (toggle.innerHTML === "Toggle dark mode") {
       toggle.innerHTML = "Dark mode it is";
     } 
       else {
       toggle.innerHTML = "Toggle dark mode"; }

    // This part I copy pasted from one of Kevin Powell's videos on darkmode switch, and maintaining persistence but still couldn't figure out howbit works...

    // check for saved 'darkMode' in localStorage
    let darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode'); 

    const darkModeToggle = document.querySelector('#mode');

    const enableDarkMode = () => {
      // 1. Add the class to the body
      document.body.classList.add('dark');
      // 2. Update darkMode in localStorage
      localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'enabled');
    }

    const disableDarkMode = () => {
      // 1. Remove the class from the body
      document.body.classList.remove('dark');
      // 2. Update darkMode in localStorage 
      localStorage.setItem('darkMode', null);
    }

    // If the user already visited and enabled darkMode
    // start things off with it on
    if (darkMode === 'enabled') {
      enableDarkMode();
    }

    // When someone clicks the button
    darkModeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
      // get their darkMode setting
      darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode'); 

      // if it not current enabled, enable it
      if (darkMode !== 'enabled') {
        enableDarkMode();
      // if it has been enabled, turn it off  
      } else {  
        disableDarkMode(); 
      }
});

    // This is the solved part I asked earlier, it chages the meta theme color with the dark or light mode change
    var meta = document.querySelector("meta[name=theme-color]");

  if (meta.getAttribute("content") === "#002f30") {
    console.log(meta.getAttribute("content"));
    meta.setAttribute("content", "#10101c");
  } else {
    console.log(meta.getAttribute("content"));
    meta.setAttribute("content", "#002f30");
  }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

While running the code, everything works fine except for the persistence part. If dark mode is enabled, and I navigate to a second page of the same html code, it turns back to default light mode. Am I doing the code right?

**P.S. I'm a novice/beginner in Javascript**

Comment: It looks like it should work.

Comment: No. Checking the mode from local storage happens only when `toggle` button is clicked. Also the button click happens automatically when page loads since it has `onclick="toggle()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// Using a local variable since stack overflow doesn't allow localstorage operations for security purposes.

let storage = {darkMode: "disabled"}

function userPreferesDarkMode() {
  //return localStorage.getItem("darkMode") === "enabled";
  return storage.darkMode === "enabled";
}

function setThemePreference(value) {
  // localStorage.setItem("darkMode", value || "disabled");
  storage.darkMode = value || "disabled";
}

const enableDarkMode = () => {
  // 1. Add the class to the body
  document.body.classList.add("dark");
};

const disableDarkMode = () => {
  // 1. Remove the class from the body
  document.body.classList.remove("dark");
};


function setTheme() {
  // If the user already visited and enabled darkMode
  // start things off with it on
  if (userPreferesDarkMode()) {
    enableDarkMode();
  } else {
    disableDarkMode();
  }
  const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
  appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>Dark mode: ${userPreferesDarkMode()}</h1>`;
}

function bootstrap() {
     const darkModeToggleButton = document.querySelector("#mode");
darkModeToggleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (userPreferesDarkMode()) {
    setThemePreference("disabled");
    disableDarkMode();
  } else {
    setThemePreference("enabled");
    enableDarkMode();
  }
  const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
  appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>Dark mode: ${userPreferesDarkMode()}</h1>`;
});

setTheme();
}

 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
     // Your code to run since DOM is loaded and ready
     bootstrap()
  });
```

```html
Live Demo

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>This is document title</title>
      <style>
      body {
  padding: 25px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.btn {
background: white;
border: 1px solid #10101c;
color: #10101c;
border-radius:0.5rem;
}

a { 
text-decoration: none;
color: #006262;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #192841;
font-style: italic;
}

body.dark {
  background-color: #10101c;
  color: #778899;
}

body.dark .btn {
background: #10101c;
color: #708090;
border: 1px solid #002e43;
border-radius:0.5rem;
}
body.dark a { 
text-decoration: none;
color: #778899;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #d5c4a1;
font-style: italic;
}
      </style>
   </head> 
   <body>
      
<div id="app">hello</div>

<button id="mode" class="btn">Toggle dark mode</button>
   </body> 
</html>
```

You have wrapped the checking of stored preference in the `toggle` method. So when you navigate to the second page, it doesn't read the value from `localstorage` until `toggle` method is invoked.

Adding a [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xtrrdf)

Comment: Would it be better to add that in a separate <script> tag and in the button section <button onclick="toggle(), setTheme()">

Comment: @SamiulJoy I have added a working demo. Note that i have called `bootstrap` function directly, you should wait till dom is fully loaded.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't working. I don't know where the problem is...but on clicking toggle button, I see nothing happening.

Comment: @SamiulJoy The stack blitz demo has everything you need right? I have added your css stylings too.

Comment: It works as in the light mode switched to dark mode and vice versa, but on loading a second page..it turns back to light mode without being persistent. Hey man thanks for trying so hard..appreciate the effort. Also, could you try tesitng it on your phone perhaps? I'm using the latest version of chrome on android. See if it works, if it does then curse my phone lol

Comment: It is working as expected in safari browser in my iPhone. Unless the localstorage is getting cleared somehow, this should definitely work.

Comment: oh! wtf! Now I feel really bad for keeping you, I'm sorry man..But what could actually go wrong with the storage! I have no idea! I've got a fair amount of free space left on my phone..that's odd.

Comment: I have deployed the same using netlify https://confident-volhard-71f43f.netlify.app/ . Do check if it works. I have added 2 pages, so you can navigate back and forth.

Comment: yes your netlify deploy works! however I'm still trying to implement it on my phone. As it's a successful answer, and since the issue is my phone, I think it'd be better off if I marked the answer as a correct one. Thank you for your answers, and sorry for all the unnecessary troubles.

Comment: works great on a single page. is there an easy way to have this localStorage persist across multiple html pages?

Comment: @Robbie yes it does. Check the netlify link https://confident-volhard-71f43f.netlify.app/